# How can I use a row value to dynamically select a column name in Oracle SQL 11g?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have two tables, one with a single row for each "batch_number" and another with defect details for each batch.  The first table has a "defect_of_interest" column which I would like to link to one of the columns in the second table.  I am trying to write a query that would then pick the maximum value in that dynamically linked column for any "unit_number" in the "batch_number".

Here is the SQLFiddle with example data for each table: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a1c27d

For example, the maximum value in the DEFECT_DETAILS.SCRATCHES column for BATCH_NUMBER = A1 is 12.

Here is my desired output:

```
BATCH_NUMBER  DEFECT_OF_INTEREST  MAXIMUM_DEFECT_COUNT  
------------  ------------------  --------------------
A1            SCRATCHES           12
B3            BUMPS               4
C2            STAINS              9
```

I have tried using the PIVOT function, but I can't get it to work.  Not sure if it works in cases like this.  Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the number of columns is fixed (it seems to be) you can use `CASE` to select the specific value according to the related table. Then aggregating is simple.

For example:

```
select
  batch_number,
  max(defect_of_interest) as defect_of_interest,
  max(defect_count) as maximum_defect_count
from (
  select
    d.batch_number,
    b.defect_of_interest,
    case when b.defect_of_interest = 'SCRATCHES' then d.scratches
        when b.defect_of_interest = 'BUMPS' then d.bumps
        when b.defect_of_interest = 'STAINS' then d.stains
    end as defect_count
  from defect_details d
  join batches b on b.batch_number = d.batch_number
) x
group by batch_number
order by batch_number;
```

See *Oracle* example in [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=0e5c46c20ab47b017eeff55a265d6701).

Comment: Thank you, that works great.  If the number of columns was larger, or if new columns were occasionally added, is there a way to automatically select the column based on the defect_of_interest value?

Comment: You'll need to add a `WHEN` clause for each new column that is added, at least in plain SQL. Alternatively, you can get the table metadata to assemble a dynamic SQL statement. But... that's not a simple thing anymore.